# Exclude certain paths for bootsnap loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails

https://github.com/Shopify/bootsnap would load all ruby files at launch. However I have certain need to not load a specific directory. Is there a configuration for doing that? Or is there a simple monkey patch to achieve the same thing?

Comment: I, too, would love this as we're seeing some intermittent issues related to `bootsnap` loading translation files from the `faker` gem when running tests in parallel on a 24-thread Mac Pro. I've created an issue for this on `bootsnap`, that will hopefully lead to an exclusion option for the gem: https://github.com/Shopify/bootsnap/issues/350

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/Shopify/bootsnap/blob/master/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/path_scanner.rb) of the gem, I've not been able to see any configuration to exclude certain paths from being cached.

However, I think you can define your paths which needs to be excluded in the following file **(monkey patching)**:

**https://github.com/Shopify/bootsnap/blob/master/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/path_scanner.rb#L39**

```rb
Dir.glob(path + ALL_FILES).each do |absolute_path|
  next if contains_bundle_path && absolute_path.start_with?(BUNDLE_PATH)
  relative_path = absolute_path.slice(relative_slice)

  // Here match your path with the relative path and skip the loop iteration  

  if File.directory?(absolute_path)
    dirs << relative_path
  elsif REQUIRABLE_EXTENSIONS.include?(File.extname(relative_path))
    requirables << relative_path
  end
end
```